# Making getline check the second and third line of input file

Tags: c++, regex, ifstream, getline

I have checked most stackoverflow questions regarding this topic but I don't seem to get the correct answer.

I am reading the strings from a txt file then I check if each line of the txt file has the correct strings using regex.

My code checks the first line of the input file and print's out "bad" if the first line of the input file is not "#FIRST". I am trying to do the same for the next two lines ,however I don't know how to tell getline to only check the second line after the first line is ok.

The second line should be "this is a comment".
The third line should be"#SECOND".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main (){



    std::ifstream input( "test.txt" );
    for( std::string line; getline( input, line ); )
{   std::regex e("#FIRST");
  std::regex b("#this is a comment");
   //std::regex c("#SECOND");

    if(std::regex_match(line,e))
    std::cout << "good." << std::endl;

else
  std::cout << "bad." << std::endl;

    if(std::regex_match(line,b))
    std::cout << "good." << std::endl;

else
  std::cout << "bad." << std::endl;
break;

}

    return 0;
}
```

input file

```
#FIRST
#this is a comment
#SECOND
```

Comment: It seems your problem isn't really with using `getline`, but is instead about how to perform several similar (but slightly different) checks in a row, am I correct? Do you need to perform any other checks on later lines in the file?

Comment: similar checks in different rows . Yeah I need to do that

Comment: Is there a check for **every** line, or are some lines not checked at all?

Comment: for every line but I want to check the first three first and add other lines later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to store a list of the checks you want to make, then loop through them. For each check, read a line and see if it matches:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> validLines {
        "#FIRST",
        "this is a comment",
        "#SECOND"
    };

    std::istringstream fileStream { // pretend it's a file!
            "#FIRST\n" \
            "this is a comment\n" \
            "this line should fail\n"};

    std::string fileLine;
    for (auto const& validLine : validLines) {
        // for every validity check, read a line from the file and check it
        if (!std::getline(fileStream, fileLine)) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to read from file!\n";
            return 1;
        }
        if (validLine == fileLine) { // could be a regex check
            std::cout << "good\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "bad\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This will only read lines that you have a check for though. If there are more lines in the file, they won't get read at all.

Also note, I made a couple of simplifications, using a string instead of a file, and using a simple match instead of a regex, but that doesn't make any difference to the bit you care about.

---

Just for fun, here's another approach if you only need to check certain line numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    using LineCheckMap = std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::string>;
    LineCheckMap validLines {
        {3, "#SECOND"}
    };

    std::istringstream fileStream { // pretend it's a file!
            "#FIRST\n" \
            "this is a comment\n" \
            "this line should fail\n"};

    std::string fileLine;
    std::size_t lineCount {0};
    while (std::getline(fileStream, fileLine)) {
        // for every line in the file, add to a counter and check
        // if there is a rule for that line
        ++lineCount;
        LineCheckMap::const_iterator checkIter = validLines.find(lineCount);
        if (std::end(validLines) != checkIter) {
            if (checkIter->second == fileLine) {
                std::cout << "good\n";
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "bad\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) I have one more question , if I want to add a valid line "SIZE 40 11 " and I want to extract the integers from the string , will I have to  make the modifications in the  `if (validLine == fileLine)` condition or should I make a seperate vector string that will compare the input against the vector string and the add a condition in the  `if (validLine == fileLine)` line?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but there is nothing to stop you storing regexs in the map, and checking those against the line from the file. I just changed your original example to use an exact string match to keep things simple.